# Android : Textedit input lost on pressing back button

Tags: android

I have an EditText in a listview which I populate via list adapter, my problem is that whenever I input any text in EditText and press back button all my changes are lost but in an another EditText at some other location(where there is no listview) everything works properly(all the changes are retained), why this is happening and how can I get rid of this problem ?

edittext code >>

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_card_list_editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/editbox_cursor_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/editbox_cursor_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_card_list_mid_gap"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_light_font"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:textSize="@dimen/forty_eight_font" >

</EditText>
```

Listadapter code >>

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    boolean convertViewWasNull = false;

    if(rowView == null){

        rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.edit_card_list_layout, parent, false);
        convertViewWasNull = true;

    }

    TextView titleview = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.edit_card_list_title);
    EditText detailview = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.edit_card_list_editText);

    if(title.get(position) != null){
        titleview.setText(title.get(position).toString());

        }
    if(detail.get(position) != null){
        detailview.setText(detail.get(position).toString());
        }else{
            detailview.setText("");
        }

    detailview.requestFocus();
    //InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //inputManager.restartInput(detailview);

    if(convertViewWasNull){

        detailview.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(detailview));

    }

    detailview.setTag(title.get(position).toString());
    return rowView;
}

private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

       private EditText view;
       private GenericTextWatcher(EditText view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            text = editable.toString();
            //save the value for the given tag :
            EditCardListAdapter.this.editTextValues.put((String) view.getTag(),text);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're tracking the edits to the field, but you're not using those edits when you create the list item view:

```
        if (detail.get(position) != null) {
            String orig = detail.get(position).toString();
            String edited = editTextValues.get(title.get(position).toString());
            detailview.setText(edited != null ? edited : orig);
        } else {
            detailview.setText("");
        }
```